# Triple Inner Join preserving headings

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day!

I have the following three tables (features, people and data)

Table Features

```
---------------------------
| featureId | featureName |
---------------------------
|     1     |   Weight    |
|     2     |     Age     |
|     3     |    Height   |
---------------------------
```

Table People

```
---------------------------
|  personId | personName  |
---------------------------
|     1     |    John     |
|     2     |     Doe     |
|     3     |    Mark     |
---------------------------
```

Table Data
(pId = personId
fId = featureId)

```
--------------------------
| id  | pId | fId | value |
--------------------------
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  80   |
|  2  |  1  |  2  |  28   |
|  3  |  1  |  3  |  175  |
|  4  |  2  |  1  |  70   |
|  5  |  2  |  2  |  22   |
|  6  |  2  |  3  |  168  |
|  7  |  3  |  1  |  100  |
|  8  |  3  |  2  |  44   |
|  9  |  3  |  3  |  180  |
--------------------------
```

I know the third table is a nightmare, but that's what I have.
Is it possible to build a query that returns (inclusive heading to be use in PHP)

```
--------------------------------
| Name | Weight | Age | Height |
--------------------------------
| John |  80    |  28 |  175   |
| Doe  |  70    |  22 |  168   |
| Mark |  100   |  44 |  180   |
--------------------------------
```

is look like a triple inner join but the heading makes it more complicate and I can't figure it out
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you want and what you have tried?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, it looked there was an error in the markup but the question was sent nevertheless. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by joining your tables and `CASE` in `MAX` function

```
SELECT
p.personName
,MAX(CASE WHEN f.featureName='Weight' THEN d.value END) Weight
,MAX(CASE WHEN f.featureName='Age' THEN d.value END) Age
,MAX(CASE WHEN f.featureName='Height' THEN d.value END) Height
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN data d ON(p.personId=d.pId)
LEFT JOIN features f ON(f.featureId=d.fId)
GROUP BY d.pId
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7913d/7)